# Empty generated vector file from psd

Tags: android, photoshop, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

I have some psd (Photoshop) file. In android studio I have created a new vector assets with these psd file. During the creation I don't have preview and the XML file generated contains only this

```
<vector android:autoMirrored="true" android:height="1121dp"
    android:viewportHeight="1121" android:viewportWidth="899"
    android:width="899dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

and, obviously, doesn't work when I try to do some like

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/psdFile" />
```

The error that I receive when I run the application is

```
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class ImageView
```

Where is the problem? Is in photoshop side or in android side?
I should use directly a PNG?

Comment: It's a problem of photoshop side. The PSD not correct to convert it ector

Comment: How I can correctly save the psd?

Comment: What's the content in your PSD?

Comment: The content is an image made with Illustrator

Answer (score 2):

There is no path in vector.
It should look like this

I think the problem is the conversion psd file into android svg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M12,4.5C7,4.5 2.73,7.61 1,12c1.73,4.39 6,7.5 11,7.5s9.27,-3.11 11,-7.5c-1.73,-4.39 -6,-7.5 -11,-7.5zM12,17c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5zM12,9c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3 3,-1.34 3,-3 -1.34,-3 -3,-3z" />
</vector>
```